# Python regex - match and replace unknown length of elements

Tags: python, regex

I have the following problem. Often data exists in a form:

`IF X = (A OR B OR C OR D)`

or

`IF X = (Aa OR Bb OR Cc)`

where 'OR' are separators and letters are values - but, number of elements in list is undefined. I want to change it to:

`IF X = 'A' OR X = 'B' OR X = 'C' OR 'D'`

and, accordingly:

`IF X = 'Aa OR X = 'Bb' OR X = 'Cc'`

I have completely no idea how to solve it by regular expression or even how to ask properly about the solution.

How to do it?

Comment: what do you mean with " larger list"? just a similar text?

Comment: are they letters or can be expression?

Comment: Also is it just `OR`? No `AND`s? You need to provide more details. Also is that a string or code? Is it always uppercase?

Comment: Please give example input and output. Your explanation is too vague

Comment: A little [modification of @MichałTurczyn regex](https://regex101.com/r/1HWbjU/3) could spare removement of `X = `

Comment: Python simply has an `in` operator, thus : `if val in [A,B,C,D]`. If you're testing membership a lot, use a set, it will be faster.

Comment: But when you show us `IF X = (A OR B OR C OR D)`, is that just pseudocode, or do you mean you're literally trying to parse SQL code?

Comment: This is a dupe of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `(\w+)(?= OR|\)$)` **after removing `X =` at the beginning**:

Explanation:

`(\w+)` - match one or more of word-characters and store it inside capturing group,

`(?= OR|\)$)` - positive lookahead with alternation: assert what follows is `OR` or `)` and end of the string

Replace it with `X = \1`, meaning replacing with `X =` followed by first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1HWbjU/1)